# Magento 2: How to get category product collection

Tags: category, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to get category product collection if `is_feature` variable **Yes**. I went around the google, but unable to get the solution.

**my code**

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class FeaturedList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected $_collection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $_resource;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper, 
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, 
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper, 
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection, 
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
            array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }


    public function getCategoryProductCollection()
    {
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature','1')->setPageSize(20)
            ->setOrder('position','asc');
        $category->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        return $category;
    }

}
```

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory`to get product collection from category,

```
    protected $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ...      
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        ...
    }

    public function getCategoryProduct($catID)
    {
        $productCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($catID)->getProductCollection();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature','1');
        $$productCollection->setPageSize(20);

        return $productCollection;
    }
}
```

Now use `getCategoryProduct()` function **.phtml** file,

```
$catID = '10';
$collection = $block->getCategoryProduct($catID);

<ul class="category-products">  
    <?php 
        foreach ($collection as $product) : ?>
            <li class="level0-child">
                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                    <?php echo $product->getName();?>
                </a>
            </li> 
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the data without `categoryId`?

Comment: Remove categoryId from  $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();

Comment: @ManojKumar see my updated answer

Comment: **Error:** Required parameter `modelId` missing.

Comment: @ManojKumar also remove categoryId from $block->getCategoryProduct(); in phtml

Comment: see updated my thread

Comment: you can add the category filter like this 
$collection = $this->_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $catId])->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature','1')->load();

Comment: @PrincePatel you have idea about that logic ? 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/281281/68695

Comment: @RakeshDonga add category filter in product collection object. Take a look into `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::getProductCollection`

Comment: @PrincePatel Thanks for suggestion i have solve my self :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Package\Modulename\Block;

class FeaturedList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $categoryFactory;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,   
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
         array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getCategoryProductCollection()
{
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load()
                ->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature','1')->setPageSize(20)
                ->setOrder('position','asc');
    $category->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    return $category;
}
```

Remove **var/generation** folder from root.

Now get product collection in your template file by calling,

```
$getCategoryProudct = $block->getCategoryProductCollection();
```

Comment: Above code is working for without category id. Get all product with is_feature is enable.

Comment: **Error:** Required parameter `modelId` missing.

Comment: can you share your block code?

Comment: see updated my thread

Comment: pleae remove class FeaturedList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct  with my block class.

Comment: still getting same Error.

Comment: pleae let me know if you have still issue.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function 
You are loading a category without any Id, how could the code will understand which category to load. So you need to provide category id.

Also, use categoryRepositoryInterface to get the category.

**here is modified code**

```
public function getCategoryProductCollection($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature','1')->setPageSize(20)
        ->setOrder('position', 'asc');
    $productCollection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds())->load();
    return $productCollection;
}
```

Comment if any error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply category filter

```
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $this->_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $catId])->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature','1')->load();
```

Note: Replace $catId with your category id.

Answer (score -1):

Get Feature Products From Product Collection Factory

```
<?php 
class FeaturedList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected $_collection;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collection
        ...
    ) {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    public function getFeaturedProductCollection(){
        $collection = $this->_collection->create();
        //$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => [1,2]) // If You want to filter Categories
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_feature', 1);
        return $collection;
    }    
}
?>
```

In Your phtml file

```
$getProudctcollection = $block->getFeaturedProductCollection();
```